# How to bind the margin of an rectangle to two sliders for top/bottom and left/right

Tags: c#, wpf, margin

I am trying to make a wpf program with an rectangle in it and two sliders at the top:

[image: Project screenshot]

The first slider changes the left/right margin of the rectangle and the right slider changes the top/bottom margin, so it makes it look like the rectangle is getting bigger and smaller. However, if you change the window size, the rectangle is adjusting.

Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="Rechteck.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        >
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Rand top/bottom</TextBlock>
            <Slider Grid.Column="0"
              x:Name="MySlider" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Minimum="10" 
              Maximum="300" 
              Value="150" 
              Margin="10" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Rand left/right</TextBlock>
            <Slider Grid.Column="1"
                x:Name="MySlider2" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Minimum="10" 
                Maximum="300" 
                Value="150" 
                Margin="10" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            <Rectangle x:Name="rechteck"          
            Width="300" 
            Height="300"
            Margin="{Binding ElementName=MySlider2, Path=Value}"
            Fill="black"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: If you want to make it bigger/smaller would it not be easier if you would bind `Width` and `Height` of the `Rectangle` to each slider instead of using `Margin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `Rectangle` to **maintain size when `Window` is resized** then instead of binding `Margin` and keeping `Width` and `Height` fixed bind them to appropriate `Slider`:

```
<Rectangle 
    x:Name="rechteck"          
    Width="{Binding ElementName=MySlider2, Path=Value}"
    Height="{Binding ElementName=MySlider, Path=Value}"
    Fill="black"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

**EDIT**

If you want `Rectangle` to **adjust to `Window` size** then don't set fixed `Width`/`Height` and `HorizontalAlignment`/`VerticalAlignment` and only bind `Margin` via custom `IMultiValueConverter`:

```
public class MarginConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Thickness((double)values[0], (double)values[1], (double)values[0], (double)values[1]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and change your `Grid` as follows:

```
<Window ... xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Namespace.For.MarginConverter">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:MarginConverter x:Key="MarginConverter"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Rand top/bottom</TextBlock>
        <Slider Grid.Column="0"
              x:Name="MySlider" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Minimum="10" 
              Maximum="300" 
              Value="150" 
              Margin="10" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Rand left/right</TextBlock>
        <Slider Grid.Column="1"
                x:Name="MySlider2" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Minimum="10" 
                Maximum="300" 
                Value="150" 
                Margin="10" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="rechteck" Fill="black">
            <Rectangle.Margin>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MarginConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="MySlider2" Path="Value"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="MySlider" Path="Value"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Rectangle.Margin>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've put `Rectangle` in the bottom row of the same `Grid` which has `Slider` as otherwise it may cover your controls when margin gets close to 0

Comment: Oh duh.  Heh, I answered his question but not his actual need.  Great answer.

Comment: thats the problem i already know this is possible but this is not what i want, because if u resize the window the rectangle is not adjusting thats why i want to bind the margin

Comment: This contradicts what you stated in question when you said _"if u change the window size, the rectangle is adjusting"_ and now you say this solution is wrong because _"if u resize the window the rectangle is not adjusting"_. So what do you want?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, with that statement i meant to say what i want and not how it works at the moment. So i want the rectangle to adjust the window if i resize.

Comment: Check my updated answer and see if that's what you want

Comment: Thank you very much thats exactly what i want. :)

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, Controls will fill the space they are given. In your case, you are giving this `rectangle` an explicit size of 300x300. Margin is internal padding that reduces the size of the control. when you re-size and shrink the `window`, the `rectangle` re-sizes to fit inside its new given bounds.

If you want the size of the `rectangle` to remain constant regardless of `window` re-sizing, I would recommend `binding` directly to the `height` and `width` properties instead of the `margin`. Also it currently looks  like you're not even using the `MySlider`, and only using `MySlider2`.

Answer (score 0):

First add a convertor somewhere

```
public class IntToThicknessConvertor : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Thickness((double)values[0], (double)values[1], (double)values[2], (double)values[3]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Thickness t = (Thickness)value;
        return new object[]{t.Left,t.Top,t.Right,t.Bottom};
    }
}
```

In you xaml make a resource pointing to your converter:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IntToThicknessConvertor x:Key="theIntToThicknessConvertor"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then in your rectangle implement multibinding:

```
        <Rectangle x:Name="rechteck"          
                    Width="300" 
                    Height="300"               
                    Fill="black"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Rectangle.Margin>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource theIntToThicknessConvertor}">
                    <Binding ElementName="MySlider" Path="Value"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="MySlider2" Path="Value"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="MySlider" Path="Value"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="MySlider2" Path="Value"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Rectangle.Margin>
        </Rectangle>
```

You'll prolly have to do some more but I hope this should get you on the right path

Comment: <local:IntToThicknessConvertor x:Key="theIntToThicknessConvertor"/> what do i have to write instead of local ? sorry for these question i am a newbie

Comment: in your Window tag you should add something like `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProjectsNameSpaceHere"`  But you should probably use @dkozl's answer instead.